# What is the difference between status code API_UNAVAILABLE and API_NOT_CONNECTED in GoogleAPI exceptions?

Tags: android, api, google-api, wearables

I am just confused between `API_UNAVAILABLE` and `API_NOT_CONNECTED` status codes in GoogleAPI exceptions. Anyone please help me finding out the difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the documentation:

**[API_UNAVAILABLE](https://developers.google.cn/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/ConnectionResult.html#API_UNAVAILABLE)**

This is one of the possible `ConnectionResult` error codes, which provides information when client fails to connect to Google Play services. These error codes are used by `GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener`.

> One of the API components you attempted to connect to is not
>   available. The API will not work on this device or for your app or for
>   this particular account, and updating Google Play services will not
>   likely solve the problem.

[**API_NOT_CONNECTED**](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/CommonStatusCodes.html#API_NOT_CONNECTED)

This is one of the CommonStatusCodes that are shared across API surfaces.

> The client attempted to call a method from an API that failed to
>   connect. Possible reasons include:
>
> - The API previously failed to connect with a resolvable error, but the user declined the resolution.
> - The device does not support GmsCore.
> - The specific API cannot connect on this device..

Answer (score 0):

**API_UNAVAILABLE:**
One of the API components you attempted to connect to is not available. The API will not work on this device, and updating Google Play services will not likely solve the problem. Using the API on the device should be avoided.

Check if you have put the correct settings and keys in the manifest. Try on different device if possible.

**API_NOT_CONNECTED:**
The client attempted to call a method from an API that failed to connect. Possible reasons include:

The API previously failed to connect with a resolvable error, but the user declined the resolution.

The device does not support GmsCore.

The specific API cannot connect on this device.